# Printing the actual regex

Tags: ruby, regex

How can I print any regex unchanged? I would like to print it to a file or console. Is there a general way to do it for any possible regex, or should I write custom methods for some set of situations?

Example regex patterns:

```
[\x20\-]{0,3}
[0-9]{0,4}\^[^\^]+\^[0-9]+\?"
```

Tried:

1. `puts URI.unescape("[\\]")`
2. `esc = URI.escape("[^\^]+\^[0-9]+\?")
   puts esc
   unesc = URI.unescape(esc)
   puts unesc`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Regexp` class has a [to_s](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Regexp.html#method-i-to_s) method that does exactly what you need.

Comment: Thanks, for the suggestion, it helped me to find the `.source` method

Answer (score 0):

Regexp.source is the correct answer. Here is an example:

```
r = Regexp.new(/[\x20\-]{0,3}[0-9]{0,4}[^0-9]/)

puts r.to_s    #PRINTS :: (?-mix:[\x20\-]{0,3}[0-9]{0,4}[^0-9])
puts r.source  #PRINTS :: [\x20\-]{0,3}[0-9]{0,4}[^0-9]
```